# Prepend Character to String in jQuery with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to add a character to the beginning of certain strings with Regular Expressions but am very new to it and can't seem to find an answer for what I'm looking for. I have strings like `Below 1499` and `Above 1900` and I want to add a `$` to the beginning of the number strings. Here's what I've got to locate the code (btw, these are all text characters in a div with a class of refinement_price_text):

```
$('.refinement_price_text').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text().match(/\d{1,5}/g));
});
```

It logs them out to the console fine. They are logged as arrays with one item. I don't know how to prepend a dollar sign to them now though. I've tried prepend() and that doesn't work. I've tried to set the match() as a variable but that didn't work. I wanted to originally use replace() but I need to maintain the current values there and just add the dollar sign character to the beginning and I didn't know what the equivalent of $(this) is for a regular expression in order to keep the same values.

Let me know if this is making sense. I'm sure there must be a function that will easily do this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this handles all possibilities:

```
"111 Above 1499 and below 14930 and $100".replace(/([^$]|^)(\b\d+)/g, "$1$$$2")
> "$111 Above $1499 and below $14930 and $100"
```

To replace the text in Jquery:

```
$(this).text(function(i, t) { return t.replace(...above stuff...) })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k7XJw/1/

To ignore numbers is parentheses,

```
str = "111 Above 1499 and below 14930(55) and $100 and (1234) and (here 123) and (123 there)"
str.replace(/([^$(]|^)(\b\d+\b)(?!\))/g, "$1$$$2")
> "$111 Above $1499 and below $14930(55) and $100 and (1234) and (here 123) and (123 there)"
```

Comment: There are multiple numbers in some of the string. For example some will say 'Above 1499 (49)' with the number in the parentheses being the quantity. How would I ignore the numbers in the parantheses and just apply it to the numbers in the string. I know this is an add-on, I just realized it's an issue though...thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there always only one price value in a string? If yes, just drop the `g` flag.

Comment: More than one in some strings.

Comment: Perfect thank you. I'm going to study your code now so I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

For simple strings like the one you posted a lookahead regex and replace will work.
Basically telling the regex to find the first number in a string (but dont consume it) and then prepend a dollar sign. For multiple numbers in the same string you will have to tweak the regex.

```
var s = "before 1900"
s=s.replace(/(?=[0-9])/,"$");
console.log(s);
```

Modified to support multiple occurences. It looks for any number preceeded by a whitespace and then prepends the dollar sign to that number.

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gEAhLI?p=preview)

```
var s = "before 1900 and 2130 and (1900)"
s=s.replace(/\s(?=\d)/g," $");
console.log(s);
```