# Adding dollar symbol in JS for a site's price refinement

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have a a site that has the following three styles of text for price refinement:

```
<span class="xyz">
    Below 20 (30)
</span>
<span class="xyz">
    39 to 45.99 (130)
</span>
<span class="xyz">
    74 and Above (216)
</span>
```

The number in brackets is quantity of items that match the price. In the first span, price is 20. In the second, price is 39 as well as 45.99. In the third span, price is 74.

What I am looking for is JS that can append the dollar symbol to prices and not to quantity, so that the final result is:

```
<span class="xyz">
    Below $20 (30)
</span>
<span class="xyz">
    $39 to $45.99 (130)
</span>
<span class="xyz">
    $74 and Above (216)
</span>
```

I found [Prepend Character to String in jQuery with Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123058/prepend-character-to-string-in-jquery-with-regular-expression), but it does not seem to be doing exactly what I want and the jsfiddle link did not work with above texts.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I cannot change the php code directly, but I can run JS.

Mansoor

Comment: prices are in variables?? your question is not clear at all. adding $ before these values works in JSFiddle.. kindly explain what exactly do you want to do. http://jsfiddle.net/dtxknz86/

Comment: Sorry I had to step out of town. Prices are auto generated by site's own template. I only have control over the css and JS. The first code set is the way it looks now, the second one is how I want it to look with a proper JS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a regex like

```js
$('.xyz').text(function(i,text){
    return text.replace(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)(?=\s)/g, function(a, b){
        return '$' + b
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="xyz">
    Below 20 (30)
</span>
<span class="xyz">
    39 to 45.99 (130)
</span>
<span class="xyz">
    74 and Above (216)
</span>
```

Comment: wont this replace all integeres without caring if it is in `span` class or not?

Comment: @vks instead of the `span` I'm using the class selector

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+\.?\d*?)(?=\s+)(?=[^><]*<\/span>([^><]*<span>[^><]*<\/span>)*[^<>]*)
```

Try this.This will replace values if they are in `span` class.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iM2wF9/12

Comment: vks, thank you for your answer. Since Arun's answer is more specific and works only for the specific class/span. I am voting for that one.

Comment: @Mansoor is `span` class imp. or not?Arun's answer will match `<div class="xyz">` as well.is thsi expected?